# No “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, facebook, nginx, cors, passport.js

I'm writing a web application using MEAN Stack and I've encountered a problem that I cannot solve, no matter what I try or search.

I'm trying to login using passport/passport-facebook with ExpressJS. If I write in the URL of my browser `localhost/api/auth/facebook` everything runs fine.

However if I create an element in my HTML code like this `<a href="/api/auth/facebook">Login with Facebook</a>` it takes me to my `404 page` (see nginx below).
And if I try with the Angular way, like this `<button ng-click="login_fb()">Login with Facebook</button>`, I get a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error.

I believe that I should use the `<a href="...">` element but I think my nginx script is blocking it, since I enabled CORS on my NodeJS Server, with this:

```
server.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
    next();
});
```

I'll leave my nginx script too (ignore the blocks inside '<' and '>'):

```
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    # To optimize the response of static files
    sendfile    on;

    server {
        # Listen to normal port
        listen      80;

        # Let through files like CSS, JPG, JS, ...
        include mime.types;

        # Alias for this server
        server_name <my-domain>;

        # Where the HTML files are located
        root <my-folder>;

        # Route for API calls
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }

        # Route for the index
        location ~ ^/*$ {
            index   index.html index.htm;
        }

        # Route for 404 page
        error_page  404 /index.html;

    }

}
```

EDIT: Using the link like this `<a href="http://localhost:8080/api/auth/facebook">Login with Facebook</a>` but it forces me to use the URL hardcoded and I'll eventually put this app under a domain.

NEW EDIT: I realise that using like this `<a href="/api/auth/facebook">Login with Facebook</a>` doesn't work because it thinks it a Angular route, and since I haven't declared in $routeProvider, it takes me to 404.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the 404, add target="_self" to your link `<a href="/api/auth/facebook">Login with Facebook</a>`. It will bypass the angular router.

With the other method, I think you get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' because when you use the angular $http service it's blocked by CORS same-origin policy at the FB API.

You should stick to the link, if you want to do this on the angular end, I recommend this plugin: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer.